# OR between two strings with 0, 1 's

Tags: r

Consider two strings of the form below:

```
101001
010001
```

How I can do OR between these two and report number of ones?

My goal is to just report 4 for the two strings above.

Thanks very much for your help

Comment: but there are  5 , 1's

Comment: Well, the combination (using OR) would be 111001 which is 4 :)

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a more elegant way, but how about this:

```
x = "101001"
y = "010001"

dat = c(strsplit(x, split=""), strsplit(y, split=""))

sum(dat[[1]] == 1 | dat[[2]] == 1)
```

or this:

```
sum(unlist(strsplit(x, split="")) == 1 | unlist(strsplit(y, split="")) == 1)
```

or, per @jbaums comment:

```
sum(as.numeric(strsplit(x, '')[[1]]) | as.numeric(strsplit(y, '')[[1]]))
```

Comment: Can simplify to `sum(as.numeric(strsplit(x, '')[[1]]) | as.numeric(strsplit(y, '')[[1]]))`, since the `0`s and `1`s are coerced to `logical` by `|`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only dealing with binary, you can convert the strings to numerics, add them, and count the number of non-zeros. (Edited to incorporate Julius's recommendation)

```
x = "101001"
y = "010001"

xy <- as.numeric(x) + as.numeric(y)

length(gregexpr("(1|2)", xy)[[1]])
```

You can write this to run over a vector pretty easily too.

```
#* function to generate sample data
make_binary_string <- function(n = 10, len = 6)
{
  vapply(1:n,
         function(i, n, len) paste0(sample(0:1, 6, replace = TRUE), collapse = ""),
         character(1),
         n = n, 
         len = len)
}

set.seed(pi)
x <- make_binary_string(n = 10)
y <- make_binary_string(n = 10)

xy <- as.numeric(x) + as.numeric(y)
nchar(gsub("0", "", xy))
```

Comment: Also could be `nchar(gsub(0, "", xy))` instead of `length(gregexpr("(1|2)", xy)[[1]])`

Comment: That's brilliant, actually...and would permit vectorization without `vapply`.

Comment: What if you have ten different numbers that you want to compare with a bitwise OR, each with a "1" at a given digit? Adding up decimal numbers and counting non-zero values is not equivalent to a bitwise OR operation.

Comment: Yup, you're right. This solution was intended for working with two strings (and could work for up to nine). For a more generalized solution, we would have to split the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I tried.

```
df <- data.frame(strsplit(str1,split = ""), strsplit(str2,split = ""))
names(df) <- c('x1', 'x2')
```

This will convert strings into dataframe like this

```
  x1 x2
1  1  0
2  0  1
3  1  0
4  0  0
5  0  0
6  1  1
```

And then count number of rows which have atleast one 1

```
nrow(df[df$x1 == 1 | df$x2 == 1,])
```

**Or**

```
sum(bitwOr(as.numeric(strsplit(str1,split = "")[[1]]) , as.numeric(strsplit(str2,split = "")[[1]])))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can define a function `to.bool()` that converts a string to a sequence of boolean values:

```
to.bool <- function(boolstr) as.logical(as.integer(unlist(strsplit(boolstr,"")))) 
sum(to.bool("101001") | to.bool("010001"))
#[1] 4
```